# WKWebView requestMediaPlaybackState(WithCompletionHandler) returns WKMediaPlaybackStatePlaying when video is not playing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

After navigating to a webpage using a WKWebView I'm polling every second to find out if there is any video media on the page and if it is playing. For many sites requestMediaPlaybackState (WithCompletionHandler) returns WKMediaPlaybackStatePlaying before the user has pressed Play on the video.

```
if (@available(iOS 15.0, *)) {
    [website requestMediaPlaybackStateWithCompletionHandler:^(WKMediaPlaybackState result) {
        if (result == WKMediaPlaybackStatePlaying) {
```

...

Comment: Same problem here. The state does not change until I navigate to a page on another domain.